# Efficient Java construct for Arraylist Processing and calling different methods

Tags: java, java-8, jaxb, java-9, java-11

Please, Is there an elegant and efficient way of doing the following in Post Java 8 i.e.
1. Looping through an arraylist
2. Reading the object
3. Calling different methods of potentially different objects using the values contained in the arraylist items

I did look at streams, switch statement, but it was much messy than my if-else.

Any help will be appreciated. Just looking for continuous improvements

```
List<JAXBElement<? extends Serializable>> bodyElements = eventRequestBodyTypeSrc.getContent();

            for(JAXBElement element: bodyElements){

                if(element.getName().getLocalPart().equalsIgnoreCase("A")){
                    methodA(element.getValue());
                }else if(element.getName().getLocalPart().equalsIgnoreCase("B")){
                     methodB(element.getValue());
                }else if(element.getName().getLocalPart().equalsIgnoreCase("C")){
                     methodC(element.getValue());
                }else if(element.getName().getLocalPart().equalsIgnoreCase("D")){
                     methodD(element.getValue());
                }else if(element.getName().getLocalPart().equalsIgnoreCase("E")){
                     methodE(element.getValue());
                }else{
                 }

            }
```

Comment: `switch` statements would look a lot cleaner than this, just saying.

Comment: If a `switch` statement looked messier than your if-else, you did something wrong.

Comment: Yes, I quickly reworked to enum and switch, but there are some interesting patterns to be explored in the answers below. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

As a lean solution I would gather all mappings first as follows:

```
Map<String, Consumer<Serializable>> dispatchers = new HashMap<>();
dispatchers.put("A", this::methodA);
// etc.
```

...and dispatch the elements like that:

```
Consumer<Serializable> dispatcher = dispatchers.get(element.getName().getLocalPart().toUpperCase(Locale.US));
if (dispatcher != null) {
    dispatcher.accept(element.getValue());
}
```

Comment: `element.getValue()` returns `Serializable`.

Comment: Thanks for the timely response. I did quickly rework my code to Enum and Switch statement. However, I will try the Consumer approach you suggested and revert. A little research will be needed, but that is fine. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a bit of an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) going on. I would refactor this at a higher level to encapsulate the strings and their related actions. Here's a rough concept using an enum:

```
enum Action {
    A("a") {
        @Override
        void doSomething(Serializable value) {
            // ...
        }
    },
    B("b") {
        @Override
        void doSomething(Serializable value) {
            // ...
        }
    };

    private static final Map<String, Action> actionsByName = Arrays.stream(values())
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(a -> a.name, a -> a));

    private final String name;

    Action(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    abstract void doSomething(Serializable value);

    public static void processElement(JAXBElement<? extends Serializable> element) {
        Action action = actionsByName.get(element.getName().getLocalPart().toLowerCase());
        if (action != null) {
            action.doSomething(element.getValue());
        } else {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of converting every string to lowercase on lookup, I’d just put the same action twice, e.g. under `"a"` and `"A"`. Or use a `TreeMap(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER)` for more complex keys. Then, using a functional interface as value, you could use a single `actionsByName.getOrDefault(element.getName() .getLocalPart(), x -> {}).doSomething(element.getValue());` statement…

Comment: Thanks for the timely response. I did quickly rework my code to Enum and Switch statement. However, I will try the Action pattern and Streams approach you suggested and revert. A little research will be needed, but that is fine. Thanks again.